# Split a text file in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a text file with several different sections. Each section has a header followed by the actual data. For example:

```
Header1
x,y,z
x,y,z
x,y,z
Header2
a,b,c
a,b,c
a,b,c
```

I want to read through the file in one pass and do different things with the data present under each section. I know how to parse the data, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to code the logic for "Do this until hitting Header2, then do something else until Header3, etc."

I'm using ruby, and I haven't really come across any examples of doing this. Any suggestions?

Comment: It seems like this would be especially simple if the processing deals with one input line at a time, and only slightly more complicated if in addition you were computing some summary statistics for each section by itself.  Is either of those scenarios a good fit to your task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the simplest you could do something like this:

```
# Process lines for header1
def do_header1(line)
  puts line.split(/,/).join("|")
end

# Process lines for header2
def do_header2(line)
  puts line.split(/,/).map{ |e| e.upcase}.join(",")
end

header1 = false
header2 = false

# Main loop
File.open("file.txt").each_line do |line|
  if line.chomp == 'Header1' # or whatever match for header1
    header1 = true
    header2 = false
    next
  end
  if line.chomp == 'Header2' # or whatever match for header2
    header1 = false
    header2 = true
    next
  end

  do_header1(line) && next if header1
  do_header2(line) && next if header2

end
```

If the number of headers becomes too high, you can start tracking headers with an integer:

```
header = -1

# Main loop
File.open("file.txt").each_line do |line|
  if line.chomp == 'Header1' # or whatever match for header1
    header = 1
    next
  end
  if line.chomp == 'Header2' # or whatever match for header2
    header = 2
    next
  end

  do_header1(line) && next if header == 1
  do_header2(line) && next if header == 2

end
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution using objects. For each line you ask each parser if a new section has started that the parser can parse.

```
class Section1Parser
  def section? potential_header
    potential_header.chomp == 'Header1'
  end
  def parse line
    puts "Section 1: #{line.split(/,/).join("|")}"
  end
end

class Section2Parser
  def section? potential_header
    potential_header.chomp == 'Header2'
  end
  def parse line
    puts "Section 2: #{line.split(/,/).join("|")}"
  end
end

parsers = [Section1Parser.new, Section2Parser.new]
selected_parser = nil

File.open("c:\\temp\\file.txt").each_line do |line|
  if new_parser_detected = parsers.detect {|p| p.section? line }
    selected_parser = new_parser_detected 
    next # skip header
  end
  selected_parser.parse line if selected_parser
end
```

Comment: This is basically the same as Sébastien Le Callonnec's solution, but cleaner and easier to extend with more sections.

Comment: This is great, and as you said, is a cleaner and more extensible solution. That said, I accepted Sébastien Le Callonnec's solution because it is what I ended up using to get the job done (I only had three Header sections to deal with).

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?

```
File.open('datafile').each_line do |s|
  if s =~ /^headerpattern$/
    #Start a new parsing block
    ...
  else
    #Parse data
    ...
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case 'Header' was in form of following string `OBJECT ObjectType ObjectNumber ObjectName`

```
if File.exist?("all.txt") then  
    object_file = File

    File.open("all.txt").each_line do |line|
        file_name = case 
            when line.match('^OBJECT Table.*')
                "TAB" + line.split[2] + ".TXT"
            when line.match('^OBJECT Form.*')
                "FOR" + line.split[2] + ".TXT"
            when line.match('^OBJECT Report.*')
                "REP" + line.split[2] + ".TXT"
            when line.match('^OBJECT Dataport.*')
                "DAT" + line.split[2] + ".TXT"
            when line.match('^OBJECT XMLPort.*')
                "XML" + line.split[2] + ".TXT"
            when line.match('^OBJECT Codeunit.*')
                "COD" + line.split[2] + ".TXT"
            when line.match("^OBJECT MenuSuite.*")
                "MEN" + line.split[2] + ".TXT"
            when line.match('^OBJECT Page.*')
                "PAG" + line.split[2] + ".TXT"
            when line.match('^OBJECT Query.*')
                "QUE" + line.split[2] + ".TXT"
        end

        unless file_name.nil? 
            File.exist?(file_name) { File.delete(file_name) }
            object_file = File.open(file_name,"w")
        end

        object_file.write(line)
    end 
end
```

But there are some prerequisites: I'm always sure that first line of the file will contain a header. I'm also not closing file (this will definitely draw my karma to the zero one day).