# Split blocks of text via heading with Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, text

Using Ruby, I'm trying to parse some documentation in which I need to split blocks of text, each with a heading and followed by an unknown length of text, and push them to an array;

```
SECTION 1. A HEADING

Some undetermined length of text,
which can be multiple lines and paragraphs.


SECTION 2. ANOTHER HEADING

Another big block of text.
```

should become

```
["SECTION 1. A HEADING

Some undetermined length of text,
which can be multiple lines and paragraphs.",
"SECTION 2. ANOTHER HEADING

Another big block of text."]
```

I could just use `string.split(/\n\n\n/)`, but I want something more specific as I can't guarantee that each section will have two blank lines after it. A little more experimenting led me to this;

```
string.split(/(?:^|\n)(SECTION.+\n)/).each do |s|
  sections << s
end
```

but I'd have to process the output again to get what I need.

Is there some way to get this done without having to do multiple passes?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just look for lines with "section n", and until you find another, keep building up a section string.

Comment: Crawling through text a line at a time with RegExes just seems a little too Perlish, I thought maybe Ruby had something a little more succinct :)

Comment: You could read the whole file file in either language and play regex games, IMO I'd rather just get it over with, because it's not an entertaining problem in its current form.

Comment: Sure, and if it was just this one example I'd have just gone for it, but I need to parse a lot of different kinds of text blocks like this. Okay, I'll look into that then. Thanks Dave.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10058330/split-a-text-file-in-ruby

Comment: Sure, I'd seen some similar ones, but I wanted to find a solution with less hoops :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [String#scan](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-scan) with multiline-mode regexp and positive look-ahead:

```
text = <<ENDTEXT
SECTION 1. A HEADING

Some undetermined length of text,
which can be multiple lines and paragraphs.


SECTION 2. ANOTHER HEADING

Another big block of text.
ENDTEXT

header = /^SECTION\s+\d+\./
sections = text.scan(/(?m)#{header}.*?(?=#{header}|\Z)/)

puts sections.join("\n---\n")

# =>
SECTION 1. A HEADING

Some undetermined length of text,
which can be multiple lines and paragraphs.



---
SECTION 2. ANOTHER HEADING

Another big block of text.
```

Comment: I had also tried scan, but without the lookahead, that's the magic! pguardiario's negative lookahead gives a cleaner RegEx but yours has a little less duplication - especially once the regex complexity increases. I'll likely combine the two. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

String#scan will give you the array you are asking for:

```
string.scan /^SECTION(?:(?!SECTION).)*/m
```

Comment: In essence the same a dbenhur's answer, though the negative lookahead is certainly cleaner. Would need to add a ^ in the lookahead otherwise this would break if SECTION was in the middle of a paragraph.

Comment: It seems unlikely but feel free to edit my answer and add the ^. Negative lookahead is very clearly superior imho.